# Asp.Net Dynamic Menu from Json or XML Data

Tags: asp.net, json, drop-down-menu, webmethod

Is there any way to get a dynamic menu for Asp.Net web application using JSON Object or XML Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes why not. Set the datasource of the asp.net menu to the xml coming from the source.

Lets create this menu in few steps.

1. In web application  add a XML file named menu.xml. The Xml Code as follow as

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <HomePage>
   <Menu text="Issue1" url="Issue1.aspx">
   <SubMenu text="Concept1" url="Concept1.aspx"></SubMenu>
   <SubMenu text="Concept2" url="Concept2.aspx"></SubMenu>
   <SubMenu text="Concept3" url="Concept3.aspx"></SubMenu>
   </Menu>
   <Menu text="Issue2" url="Issue2.aspx">
   <SubMenu text="Problem1" url="Problem1.aspx"></SubMenu>
   <SubMenu text="Problem2" url="Problem2.aspx"></SubMenu>
   <SubMenu text="Problem3" url="Problem3.aspx"></SubMenu>
   </Menu>
   </HomePage>`
2. Add the XMLDataSource Control to the page from the Data tab of the Toolbox.
3. Link the DataSourceID as XmlDataSource1 for the Menu control and the menu.xml as DataFile of XmlDataSource control and bind the menu control.

The code for menu control is

```
<asp:Menu ID="dymenu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlsource1" Orientation="Horizontal">
<DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#228B22" />
<StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFBB77" />
<DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFAA99" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
<StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#abcdaa" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Menu>
```

The code for XmlDataSource is

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/menu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Here I am using XML File , you can also use dynamic xml instead of the static xml.

Comment: Thank you,Is there any option of reading xml data from a service rather than a file ? Basically my service does return xml data.want to load the menu based on dynamic XML data sent by service,Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, Following to your explanation  have tried passing an aspx page(which returns xml data) to Datafile. and used XPath attribute. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

Write the Following in ASPX Body Tag

```
<asp:Menu ID="menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="source1" Orientation="Horizontal">
<DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#228B22" />
<StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFBB77" />
<DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FFAA99" />
<DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
<StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#abcdaa" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Menu>
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="source1" runat="server" DataFile="~/menu.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

and Run....